# Unable to load DLL 'cvextern' on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, web-applications, deployment, emgucv, azure-web-app-service

EmguCV version 3.0.0 will work fine, if you publish your web app on Azure.

I am trying to find a solution for EmguCV 3.3.0, but no luck yet.
I get Unable to load DLL 'cvextern'

If you have any suggestions please reply.

Comment: When exactly do you receive this error message? Have you migrated a website to Azure App Service WebApp as outlined here:https://www.migratetoazure.net/? 

You may use Kudu Console: This will give you a web-based dashboard, including a debug console (web-based) where you can explore your various directories.
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have used Kudu-console and I have tried to investigate if my Azure Web App runs C++ redistributable 2015 and if that has any connection with my issue above. I will try your migration advise to see what happens and get you back.